# How do I add a DigiCert as a Certificate Authority to Azure Key Vault Programmatically?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault, ca

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-integrate-certificate-authority) says how to add DigiCert as a Certificate Authority via the Azure portal or via PowerShell, but I need to do it via Python/REST/ARM templates.

Answer (score 1):

I opened up a case with Microsoft for this and they were kind enough to send me a good docs link. Right now (2021-05-20), there's no way to do this via the Python SDK or ARM templates, but you *can* add Certificate Authorities via the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/setcertificateissuer/setcertificateissuer).

Here's an example using `az rest` after I have logged in with `az login`:

```sh
    readonly vaultBaseUrl="https://concert-kv-dev-bbk-01.vault.azure.net/"
    readonly issuerName="digicert-bbkane-com-03"
    readonly resource="https://vault.azure.net"

    set -x

    az rest \
        --body "@body.json" \
        --method put \
        --resource "$resource" \
        --uri "${vaultBaseUrl}/certificates/issuers/${issuerName}" \
        --uri-parameters 'api-version=7.2'
```

Here's the contents of `body.json`:

```json
{
  "provider": "DigiCert",
  "credentials": {
    "account_id": "###",
    "pwd": "password"
  },
  "org_details": {
    "id": "###"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can certainly write a Python script to do this as well using the REST endpoint.  That's all one released by MS would do anyway.

Comment: @MattSmall, that's exactly what my next steps will be :). I need to do it from an Azure Function